# Webkit 3D CSS. Rotate camera like in a First Person Shooter

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit, 3d

What I want to achieve is a camera rotation like http://www.keithclark.co.uk/labs/3dcss/demo/ . It's not perfect and sometimes the camera breaks, but that's the idea.

I like the rotation to be similar like a human view, but I only managed to obtain a rotation across a certain point. This is an example of what I obtained http://jsfiddle.net/gaAXk/3/.

As i said before, i would like a human like behaviour.

I also tried with -webkit-transform-origin but with no better result.

Any help/suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't the first link give you the code to what you want? Can you set the "certain point" to the same point as the camera? Or is that what you were doing with transform-origin and it didn't work? Possibly you could add buttons or keyboard events to test the rotation instead of the mouse until you get it working?

Comment: ok, i updated the example http://jsfiddle.net/gaAXk/6/ 'Q' and 'E' keys would rotate the camera now. From what I understood in the first link, the transformation-origin coordinates (without z) are the opposites of translate3d coordinates, and z is equal to perspective-origin. This is what i tried in http://jsfiddle.net/gaAXk/5/ and it doesn't work as expected. Probably a misunderstanding of concepts, in webgl with three.js seems much easy. I need this in CSS. First link has some flaws, if you go to the center of the room and rotate, it will rotate across the monitor which it's not what i want

Answer (score 7):

The problem here is the following:

To give a human-like behavior, **when the point of view moves, you should calculate the new positions on the x/y/z axis for the objects** (not just the rotation angle in case of a rotation, for instance).

CSS transform should work in the follwing way, we give a **perspective**, for example of 800px to a scene. Then the objects will be visible **with a Z position up to 800px**, if the Z position is, for example 1000px, it will be behind our point of view, so we won't be able to see the element.

That said, after a rotation you should calculate the new position for the items based on our new point of view.

To be clearer **I've updated your example with much simpler code** (it only supports rotation and there's just one image): http://jsfiddle.net/gaAXk/12/

- The *perspective* in the example is *800px*.
- The image is initially placed at *x=0px, y=0px, z=0px*. So it will be visible in front of us at a "distance" of 800px.
- When we *rotate* the point of view, the element should *move along a circumference around the point of view*, so the x,z positions and the rotation angle of the element, needs to be updated.

The element in the example moves along a circumference with 800px radius (the *calculatePos()* function does the trick).

The same calculation should be updated if we change position (if the point of view gets closer to some objects, and further from others).

This isn't so trivial. If anyone has better solutions (I'm not a 3D expert), I will be glad to hear some.